# VBA SaveAs Method

Tags: excel, save, vba

After browsing forums for well over an hour, I can't seem to figure out why my save as code isn't working.

My goal is to save a new copy of the workbook under a different file type. (The current file type is .csv.) I'm not trying to save in a new or different location, the current directory is where I want it to save to.

I've tried more variations of the following code than I can remember, so I'll just post my current syntax:

`CurrentDir = CurDir()`

`dateVal = Date`

`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="" & CurrentDir & "ALS Week of " & dateVal - 4 & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51`

I've looked at examples of how to open a dialog box wherein the user inputs information in order to save. But I'm hoping for a hands-off approach. If anyone can see where my error lies, please let me know!

*EDIT:*
 The error that I get is `"Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed`

Comment: Do you get some kind of error number with the error?

Comment: Just a runtime 1004 error.

Comment: Which version of Excel do you use? Are you trying to overwrite an existing file?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2010. No, this filename does not already exist.

Comment: What is the value of `Debug.Print "" & CurrentDir & "ALS Week of " & dateVal - 4 & ".xlsx"`  just before your saveas line?

Comment: It is (edited for privacy reasons) "\\filepath\folder1\folder2\folder3\2013\folder5\4-29 Class\ALS Week of 4/29/2013.xlsx"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your date has [illegal characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#naming_conventions) in it. Format your date with dashes and not slashes and this won't happen.

```
The following reserved characters:

    < (less than)
    > (greater than)
    : (colon)
    " (double quote)
    / (forward slash)
    \ (backslash)
    | (vertical bar or pipe)
    ? (question mark)
    * (asterisk)
```

Comment: You nailed it, Brad! Works like a charm now. Thank you all so much for your time and responses!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a backslash:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= CurDir() & "\ALS Week of " & (Date - 4) & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
```

Comment: Thank you for the timely response! You're right! I forgot the backslash. However, after inserting the backslash, I still got the error message. Thoughts?